# Failure while deploying a PlayFramework application to tomcat 6

Tags: java, playframework, tomcat6

I'm trying to deploy a play application as a war in TOMCAT 6 and I get the following error :

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
Deploying web application archive test1.war
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
validateJarFile(/Users/olivier/Apps/tools/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/webapps/test1/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Starting /Users/olivier/Apps/tools/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/webapps/test1/WEB-INF/application
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/test1] startup failed due to previous errors
```

There are 2 errors :

1) The servlet spec different version

2) And the error in the ContextListener

I'm not sure if the error 2) is due the error 1).

To be sure it was not something of my app or my tomcat, I used a new tomcat (6.0.35) with nothing else than the play app and created a new empty play app like this :

$ play new test1

Then I created the war 
$ play war -o /xxx/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/webapps/test1  --zip

But I got the same error.

I'm running on MacOsX with java 1.6 and play 1.2.4

```
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-11D50b)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)
```

Am I doing something wrong, did I miss something ?

**Edit : I tried to deploy the exactly same war in jetty 7.6.2 and it worked perfectly.**

Thanks,

Olivier

Answer (score 0):

You should never EVER add the servlet.jar file to your webapp /WEB-INF/lib folder! This file is already provided by your web container.

Comment: I totally agree. But as mentioned in the post, the war has been generated automatically by the play framework. So the question is why play! generates the war with it and why the spec version is different from the tomcat6's one (when play! says it supports tomcat6)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.2.jar from the application/lib of your war file.